# How to display fields of parent list and foreign list using spquery

Tags: spquery

I have created parent list that lookup to another list . Both the list having one identical column label but different values(column name: displayorder).I projected the displayoreder column from foreign list as
`<Field Name='DisplayOrder'     Type='Lookup' List='SectionTypeList' showField='DisplayOrder'/>`
Where sectionTypeList is foreign list. I created view field query as
`<FieldRef Name='DisplayOrder'/>`
`<FieldRef List='SectionTypeList' Name='DisplayOrder'/>`

This is not working. Please reply me if my question is not specific